# How do i parse the Ping-Time(integer) of an Ping request(string)?

Tags: java, android, parsing, process, ping

I'm quite new to Android Programming and I'm not that experienced with Java/Android Programming. I wanted to make an app, which pings an address entered by the user.

So I found a quit nice script, which does an ICMP Ping Request to an address and gives back the output of the command-line. (In fact it's just the Ping-command, which is ran in an process):

```
public String ping(String url){
    int count = 0;
    String str = "";
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + url);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
            output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        reader.close();
        //int time = Integer.parseInt(output[10])
        // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
        str = output.toString();
        str = str.substring(str.indexOf("time="), str.indexOf("ms"));
        //str = output.toString();
        // Log.d(TAG, str);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // body.append("Error\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Output:

```
time = 43
```

However I don't really understand what everything does here, because it's an script from the Internet. Because I'm just interrested in the time of the response, I want to parse it and turn it into an Integer.

In my opinion there are two possibilities

- Modify the ping command to just give back the time
- Parse the Integer of the time out of the String

I never worked with that kind of stuff, so I wanted to ask you guys if you could help me. :)

Comment: What is the question? Did you executed this code? Try to debug it to understand it better.

Comment: As you can read in my Title i want to parse the TTL/Respond time out of the String^^ but how do i do so?

Comment: Parse the output, use regex or simple String replace. It depends on the output. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried it now with substring str = str.substring(str.indexOf("time="), str.indexOf("ms"));

Comment: And? What happened? Got exception? Didn't get what you expected? Share your full code, edit your post.

Comment: Look above i edited my main thread

Comment: Looks like it worked no?

Comment: Yeah but how to turn that whole thing into an Integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in few ways:

## 1

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("=") + 1, str.indexOf("ms")).trim();
int result = Integer.valueOf(str);
```

## 2

```
str = str.replace("time=", "").replace("ms", "").trim();
int result = Integer.valueOf(str);
```

## 3

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output.toString());
matcher.find();
String result = matcher.group();
int result = Integer.valueOf(str);
```

## 4

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```